# Ошибка входа microsoft sql server management studio

Tags: sql-server, sql

Привет.

Провел установку microsoft sql server 2012.

У меня ошибка входа:

[image]

Просьба помочь или дать ссылку на описание и решение данной проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас не запущена служба SQL. Откройте список служб (нажмите Win+R, затем в появившейся командной строке вбейте services.msc)
В появившемся окне перечислены службы Windows. Найдите там что-то вроде SQL Server или MS SQL Server и выберите в контекстном меню "Запустить". После запуска должно заработать

[image]

Comment: Благодарен .... Ура. Двигаюсь дальше в изучении.